# Code Assist never worked

Tags: configuration

Working with Mathematica 11.1.1.0 - code assist does not work at all.  All the Options Inspector fields seem correct. Could be some missing files from `$BaseDirectory`? That directory does contain a file "CodeAssistHistory9.0.m" does seems odd.

Mathematica 6 and 9 were both loaded on this machine.  Could it be that the installation failed to copy some files as a result.

I could try a reinstall but the first install had problems that Wolfram support took about 10 days to resolve.

Comment: Can you give some details on what you tried and what you expected (but failed) to see?

Comment: I've had the code assist stop working on me several times in the last 2 days. I couldn't find any options that were changed and the only way I found to restore it, is to blitz most of the non-essential stuff  in `$UserBaseDirectory`. A colleague of mine has the same problem. Maybe some paclet Wolfram pushed in the last few days?